# Implementing retry budget with RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, microservices

After having read the exceptionally well written Site Reliability Engineering (https://landing.google.com/sre/book.html) I've become interested in implementing a generic retry budget for our RPC clients.

The case is that given a client to a service I want to automatically perform retries to deal with timeout's, slow io etc.
At the same time I don't want to participate in a thundering herd causing already slow systems to be even more unresponsive.

The book describes the concept of a retry budget where my client against a system is only allowed to retry globally up to i.e. 10% of the normal load against the server. This concept requires windowing, global state over threads etc. This in conjunction with our clients that already relies on RxJava to deal with concurrency leads me to consider using Rx to keep the state of when retries are allowed.

Before I get ahead of myself and implement the feature it would be interesting to hear if anyone else has done anything similar or know of any frameworks / libs that does the same?

The only framework I've seen so far is Finagle, but as we're a Java / JS shop (no Scala, yet..) it's a no go for us.

Comment: I'd suggest lookinf into Hystrix for global state like that

Comment: Thanks. We're actually already using Hystrix which does not deal with retries (as per design) but rather leaves it to the enclosed rpc client.